# Is there any way to get the code coverage of a Concordion tests?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, concordion

I have a Java Project with Concordian and Maven, and I would like to know if is there a way to get the code coverage of a Concordion tests?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). It has a [Maven plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) and can run locally or remotely.

Comment: I'm using JaCoCo on my project and it works perfectly for unit testing, but I wasn't able to run Jacoco + Concordion and see the tests results :(

Comment: Would you provide a bit more detail about how you have Jacoco + Concordion configured and the issues you are seeing with it?